# What is the relationship between inverted index and field in solr

Tags: solr

Forgive me I just a newbie of Solr. I am trying to understand some basic concept of Solr.

I quoted some read about inverted index as following .

> This is like retrieving pages in a book related to a keyword by
>   scanning the index at the back of a book, as opposed to searching
>   every word of every page of the book.
>
> This type of index is called an inverted index, because it inverts a
>   page-centric data structure (page->words) to a keyword-centric data
>   structure (word->pages).

In my understanding. I think the index would indicate the specific token term pointing to some document. But I can't understand what does  the field of document use for when in the indexing and query?

In my understanding. in the query . Solr just search in the index and find the document. It is nothing to do with the field . Right ?Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for that . I just found something value in the internet. http://www.solrtutorial.com/basic-solr-concepts.html. `An index consists of one or more Documents, and a Document consists of one or more Fields.`

Answer (score 1):

Documents (which can have one or more fields) are the I/O entities exchanged between client and server during the index and the query phases. The inverted index is a low-level concept (hidden to the client) and it is the immutable and underlying data structure that solr uses to organize its data.

Solr uses fields for searching and indexing. Document instead  is a logical grouping of them. (Improperly) speaking in RDBMS terminology

Document = record
Field = columns values belongin to that record

Comment: Sorry for the updating. Please help to review my question. thanks.

Comment: I just can't not understand . Why need field in the query and indexing. Thanks.

Comment: Fields contain values that are indexed (first) and then searched (later). Solr (but the same is valid for a RDBMS) is a tell-and-ask system: first, you put data (values, i.e. fields, i.e. documents) and then you search

Comment: So the index is for the specific field . Right ? Thanks.

Comment: If you are wondering about documents and fields, I'm not sure if it is so useful to get the point about the internal index organization. However there's some truth in your last sentence so yes you could think in those terms, if that helps you

Comment: Yes. I think if it is YES. The index will looks like `some token ------- exist in the A field(Position is xx) of B document` . I think it is important to understand the index data structure.. Thanks.

Comment: Let say's there is a field named A in the document B . Thanks.